# jvm hanging while connecting to database

Tags: dynamic-proxy

hi in websphere application jvm is hanging twice in two months crashing the entire application,so need to know whether it is because of slow database connection or driver issue.The log snippet is

```
    There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:155)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:283)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamW.rapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1084)
    at  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:359)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at com.common.database.ResultSetHandler.invoke(ResultSetHandler.java:44)
    ** at $Proxy1.next(Unknown Source)**
    at com.common.database.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:597)
    at com.common.database.PreparedStatementHandler.invoke(PreparedStatementHandler.java:47)
    **at $Proxy0.executeQuery(Unknown Source)**
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see a hanging occurring while invoking the `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0()` method, then it could be potentially due to several reasons.

1. A network issue between your IBM WebSphere Application Server and the remote resource (in your case the Oracle Database)
2. The application is simply reading a large amount of data.
3. The Oracle Database isn't responding or it's experiencing a performance issue resulting in a slow response.

You can find more information in the IBM link below:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610001